# Playframework JavaWS logs correct curl script but not works correctly

Tags: java, playframework, ws

I am trying to send email via web service. The curl script which is logged by `AhcCurlRequestLogger` works fine when I paste it into terminal. But service method not work. The code does not enter `wsResponse` part.

The java function:

```
public CompletionStage<String> sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content) {

    JsonNode requestBody = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode()
            .put("username", this.apiUsername)
            .put("api_key", this.apiKey)
            .put("from", this.mailFrom)
            .put("bcc", this.mailBcc)
            .put("reply_to", this.mailFrom)
            .put("recipient", to)
            .put("subject", subject)
            .put("campaign_name", subject)
            .put("raw_html", content);

    return ws.url(this.apiUrl)
            .setRequestFilter(new AhcCurlRequestLogger())
            .post(requestBody)
            .thenApply((WSResponse wsResponse) -> {
                int responseStatus = wsResponse.getStatus();
                if (responseStatus >= 200 && responseStatus < 300) {
                    log.info("An email with subject " + subject + " was sent successfully to: " + to);
                    return "Mail was sent successfully.";
                } else {
                    log.error("An email with subject " + subject + " could not send successfully to: " + to);
                    return "Mail could not sent successfully.";
                }
            });
}
```

The curl script:

```
  [info] p.l.w.a.AhcCurlRequestLogger - curl \
    --verbose \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{
    "username" : "secret_username",
    "api_key" : "secret_key",
    "from" : "some@mail.com",
    "bcc" : "some@mail.com",
    "reply_to" : "some@mail.com",
    "recipient" : "some@mail.com",
    "subject" : "top_secret",
    "campaign_name" : "top_secret",
    "raw_html" : "<h3>super mail</h3>"
  }' \
    'https://madmimi.com/api/v3/transactionalEmails'
```

I have not any error log. I am using playframework 2.7.3 version. I though that ssl verification may cause this. So i added ssl certificate chain to trustStore. It does not work. Then I removed it and add

```
play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate = true
```

to `application.conf`. It also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The logging in your code snippet will run only if the promise returned by `.post(requestBody)` completes successfully. Therefore it would seem that there is an exception preventing the promise from completing.

To handle this situation you can add the `exceptionally`-method:

```
    return ws.url(this.apiUrl)
        .setRequestFilter(new AhcCurlRequestLogger())
        .post(requestBody)
        .thenApply((WSResponse wsResponse) -> {
            ...
        })
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            log.error("The request failed", throwable);
            return "Mail could not be sent successfully.";
        });
```

When you get the error logged it might be obvious how to fix it. If not, add the error to the question.